# Copying values to a static class property using reflection - System.Reflection.TargetException

Tags: c#, reflection

I am adding methods to a static class to copy all property values of a non static class instance to a static class instance. I am getting the following exceptions:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetException' in mscorlib.dll
> System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
> at Dispensing.Classes.Options.CopyPropertiesFromSource(Object source) in C:\Users\erics\source\repos\TestingEFClassLibrary\TestingEFClassLibrary\Classes\Options.cs:line 32

My static class looks like this:

```
    public static class Options
{
    public static bool DispenseFile { get; set; }
    public static Units Units { get; set; }
    public static AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
    public static DispenseStyle DispenseStyle { get; set; }
    public static double Volume { get; set; }

    public static void CopyPropertiesFromSource(object source)
    {
        Type t = typeof(Options);
        var destinationProperties = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); 
        var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties();

        foreach (var destinationProperty in destinationProperties)
        {
            foreach (var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
            {
                if (destinationProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name && destinationProperty.PropertyType == sourceProperty.PropertyType)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(destinationProperty.Name);
                        destinationProperty.SetValue(t, sourceProperty.GetValue(sourceProperty));

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the exceptions on the line:

```
destinationProperty.SetValue(t, sourceProperty);
```

When this happens the destinationProperty is Boolean and the sourceProperty is also Boolean.

**EDIT** - The answer was in the comments below from @theHennyy. Here is the corrected offending line. This worked:

```
destinationProperty.SetValue(null, sourceProperty.GetValue(source));
```

Comment: You need to expand the example including the source object that is used to generate the exception.

Comment: The first argument of `SetValue` should probably be `null`, because you the property you are trying to set is static. Also the first argument of the `GetValue` call is probably wrong, it should be `source`.